# Spring mvc annotation - javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'isOnline' not found on type it.besmart.models.Luce - but there is

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Good morning all...

I have my application with Spring MVC which was working well.. Than I added a new field in a table, updated my model, but I'm getting the error in the title.
I'm getting the error only in the list view, in the detail page, with the same syntax, it works...

My model

```
@Entity
@Table(name="luci", catalog="SMARTPARK", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "id_luce"))
public class Luce implements java.io.Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int idLuce;
    private Integer numeroLuce;
    private String nomeLuce;
    private String descrizione;
    private boolean stato;
    private Client client;
    private boolean isOnline;


public Luce(){}

public Luce(int idLuce, Integer numeroLuce, String nomeLuce, String descrizione, boolean stato, Client client, boolean isOnline){
    this.idLuce = idLuce;
    this.numeroLuce = numeroLuce;
    this.nomeLuce = nomeLuce;
    this.client = client;
    this.descrizione = descrizione;
    this.stato = stato;
    this.isOnline = isOnline;
}

@NotNull
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id_luce", unique = true, nullable = false)
public int getIdLuce() {
    return idLuce;
}

public void setIdLuce(int idLuce) {
    this.idLuce = idLuce;
}


@NotNull
@Column(name="numero_luce", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getNumeroLuce() {
    return numeroLuce;
}

public void setNumeroLuce(Integer numeroLuce) {
    this.numeroLuce = numeroLuce;
}

@NotEmpty
@Size(max=50)
@Column(name="nome_luce", unique = true, nullable = false)
public String getNomeLuce() {
    return nomeLuce;
}

public void setNomeLuce(String nomeLuce) {
    this.nomeLuce = nomeLuce;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="client")
public Client getClient() {
    return this.client;
}

public void setClient(Client client) {
    this.client = client;
}

@Size(max=255)
@Column(name="descrizione")
public String getDescrizione() {
    return descrizione;
}

public void setDescrizione(String descrizione) {
    this.descrizione = descrizione;
}


@Column(name="stato")
public boolean isStato() {
    return stato;
}

public void setStato(boolean stato) {
    this.stato = stato;
}

@Column(name="is_online")
public boolean isOnline() {
    return isOnline;
}

public void setOnline(boolean isOnline) {
    this.isOnline = isOnline;
}

}
```

then in the controller I have a simple

```
@RequestMapping(value = { path }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listSpots(ModelMap model) {
        List<Luce> luce = luceService.showLights();
        model.addAttribute("luce", luce);

        return path + "/luci";
    }
```

which worked until this morning...
The view part is

```
<c:forEach items="${luce}" var="light">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="list-field">${light.numeroLuce}</div></td>
            <td><div class="list-field">${light.nomeLuce}</div></td>
            <td><div class="list-field">${light.client.nomeClient}</div></td>
            <td><span class="text-success">

            <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${light.stato == true}" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span></c:when>
                <c:otherwise><span class="text-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span></span></c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
            </span></td>
            <td><span class="text-success">
            <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${light.isOnline == true}" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span></c:when>
                <c:otherwise><span class="text-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span></span></c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
            </span></td>
            <td class="actions"><a class="pull-right" href="<c:url value='/lights/${light.idLuce}' />"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></td>
        </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

I just added the `light.isOnline == true` part, and got the error.
Just to say that in another view I have the details of the single light, and it works..

Comment: do `test=${light.online}` you don't need anything more.

Comment: can you change from light.isOnline == true to light.isOnline eq true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the bean method `isOnline()`.

Change the method name to - `getIsOnline()` and it should work fine.

When you use expression language, it automatically appends get and capitalize first character of the variable to get to the getter method. There is no `getIsOnline()` method in your bean and the reason for this error.

**EDIT**:

As per java bean variable naming specs, change the name of the boolean field to `online` and then the `isOnline()` method will work fine.

Comment: You are basically recommending to stop adhering to the Java Bean specs. The property is named `online` and not `isOnline`.

Comment: @M.Deinum: Check carefully, the property is named isOnline and not online.

Comment: You are right, didn't notice that, but still it would fail because it is a `boolean` so it would become `isIsOnline` instead of `getIsOnline` the latter would work for a `Boolean` not for a `boolean`.

Comment: Yes, the alternate solution and a better one is to change the property name to online instead of isOnline.

Comment: I still don't agree, it will work for boolean as well. I guess it checks and appends both get and is to get the result. It will not follow the java bean specs if the method name is getIsOnline() but it will still work fine.

Comment: That might depend on the EL version/implementation used.

Comment: @M.Deinum: Right, it will work for recent versions for EL implementations.

Comment: @besmart: Accept the answer in that case.

Comment: I changed the db field name in 'online' and now it works perfectly, still I cannot understand while in the other view il worked before..

Answer (score -2):

The problem is your test expression.

```
<c:when test="${light.isOnline == true}"
```

You expect a property `isOnline` and test it for `true`. However there is no `online` property there is an property called `isOnline`, which would lead to a "getter" of `isIsOnline` instead.

Also testing it for `true` isn't really needed as that is the point of the `test` attribute.

Basically rewriting to the following should make it work

```
<c:when test="${light.isIsonline}"
```

This will look for a property `isOnline` and because it is a `boolean` and not a `Boolean` it will call the `isIsOnline` method in your class. If you don't want to you need to explicitly call the method and if that is doable depends on the EL version you are using.

```
<c:when test="${light.isOnline()}"
```

Comment: The property is named isOnline and not online. Please read caefully.